# hibernate component annotation table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

is it possible to configure Hibernate annotations to store a component class in a separate table?

Take the following example:

```
@Table(name = "A")
@Entity
public class A implements Serializable {
@Id
public String id;

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="ENTITY_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private Set<ComponentObj> components;
....
}
```

For the component table...

```
@Table(name = "C")
public class ComponentObj implements Serializable {

@JoinColumn(name="ENTITY_ID")
public String entity_Id;

....
}
```

When I start to perform unit testing with the above annotations, I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: ComponentObj
```

I have declared both classes as annotated classes...

Answer (score 1):

I would advise making ComponentObj a real entity, with an identifier, and simply using a OneToMany association.

It's possible to have a colelction of components, but not the way you tried.

- the component class must be annotated with `@Embeddable`
- the collection must be annotated with `@ElementCollection`
- the component must not have an entity_Id field
- the table to use must be specified using a `CollectionTable` annotation on the collection

A complete example is available in [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/CollectionTable.html).

Comment: Thanks. It helped a lot.